# Lim Sup as Eventual Upper bound (Beginner question)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

According to Wikipedia, The limit superior of ${\displaystyle x_{n}}$ is the smallest real number ${\displaystyle b}$  such that, for any positive real number ${\displaystyle \varepsilon }$, there exists a natural number ${\displaystyle N}$ such that ${\displaystyle x_{n}<b+\varepsilon }$ for all ${\displaystyle n>N}$.

Just to confirm, can we say that since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, $\limsup x_n$ is the smallest real number $b$ such that there exists $N$ such that $$x_n\leq b$$ for all $n>N$?

Somehow I don't see the above statement in books, so I have a slight doubt on whether it is true or not.

Thanks for verifying!

Update: Thanks. I see now that it is wrong. I think the reason it is wrong is because $N$ depends on $\epsilon$, and when $\epsilon\to 0$, $N$ may tend to infinity. Is that why it is wrong?

Comment: No. Consider $x_n=1/n$. Then $\limsup x_n=0$, but $x_n>0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement you have made is not true at all. For example, suppose that $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$. Then, $\limsup a_n = 0$, but then $a_n > 0$ for all $n$.

The correct statement is made as follows:

> $\limsup a_n$ is the largest $x$ such that there is a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ of $a_n$ which converges to $x$, or the supremum of these $x$, if no such largest element specifically exists.

This is clearly different from what you have written. Please see the difference in the statements.

Comment: Sorry, this is an old post but could you clarify why the sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ is a counter example to the statement that "lim sup ($a_n$) is the smallest $b$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that $x_n < b+ \epsilon$ for all $n > N$"?

Comment: We have that lim sup $(\frac{1}{n}) = 0$, and for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exits $N$ such that $\frac{1}{n} <  0 + \epsilon$ for all $n > N$

Comment: And surely $0$ is the smallest such number?

Comment: @3891780 the statement you give is correct. But in the question above, the "just to confirm" part is contradicted by the example I give.

Comment: I see, thank you

Comment: @3891780 You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

As the others pointed out, $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ is a counterexample.

However, if there is a $b$ with the property you describe, then it is the limsup.  To see this, let $L$ be the limsup, and $b$ as you describe in your question.  Suppose $b>L$, and $\epsilon$ small so that $L+\epsilon< b$.  Then, by definition, there is an $N$ such that $x_n < L + \epsilon < b$ for all $n\geq N$.  Therefore $L + \epsilon$ satisfies your condition, but is smaller than $b$, which is a contradiction.  Suppose $b<L$ and $\epsilon$ small enough that $b + \epsilon < L$.  Then there is an $N$ such that for all $n>N$, we have $x_n \leq b < ( L - \epsilon ) + \epsilon$.  This shows that $L - \epsilon$ satisfies the condition in the definition of limsup, so that $L$ can't be the smallest such number, so that's a contradiction.  Therefore $b=L$.

However, there is no guarantee that such a $b$ exists!  As in the case of $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Very interesting. (+1)