# Property of limit superior(inferior)

Tags: calculus

I will frame this question for limit superior but it can equivalently be considered in terms of limit inferior in the obvious way.

The wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) on limit superior states: 
"The limit superior of $x_{n}$ (if finite) is the smallest real number $b$ such that, for any positive real number $\varepsilon$ , there exists a natural number $N$ such that $x_n < b + \varepsilon$ for all $n > N$."

I have a very strong feeling that statement is incorrect, however I'm not able to find a counterexample. A similar question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956378/lim-sup-as-eventual-upper-bound-beginner-question) and the given counterexample was $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$. However, it seems to me that lim sup ($\frac{1}{n}$) = $0$ *does* does satisfy the conclusion of the quoted statement.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct. You have that $$\ell=\limsup_{n\to \infty }x_n=\lim_{n\to \infty }\sup_{k\geq n}x_k.$$

Therefore, for all $\varepsilon >0$, there is $N\in\mathbb N$ s.t. for all $n\geq N$ $$|\sup_{k\geq n}x_k-\ell|<\varepsilon .$$

Notice that $n\mapsto \sup_{k\geq n}x_k$ is decreasing, therefore for all $\varepsilon >0$, there is $N\in\mathbb N$ s.t. for all $n\geq N$, $$x_n\leq \sup_{k\geq n}x_k\leq \ell+\varepsilon ,$$
and of course $\ell$ is the smallest real number with this property.